# declare 2d vector in header, fill in .cpp

Tags: c++, visual-studio

right now i have it so that in a class's header, i declare/fill a vector like so:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> v
{
    { 0,0,0 },
    { 0,0,0 },
    { 0,0,0 }
};
```

then i do some other stuff in the .cpp file. 
what i want to do is declare the vector in the header, then initialize it in the same simple way in the .cpp.

also, the main reason i brought this up is because when i change values in that vector, then i build it and output some values, they dont actually change unless i fully rebuild the solution. my assumption is that theres something going on with the compiler (visual studio), and the way im actually filling in the vector's data in the header instead of the cpp. i think maybe the compiler ignores the details of the vector. (maybe it only reads the vector's size, not the actual data in the header, and thinks its the same, so it doesnt recompile the header?)

Comment: You should not normally be defining vectors in a header file.

Comment: Sounds like the build system does not include the header files in the build dependencies, so if you just change the header, the builder will not detect any changes and not actually recompile.

Comment: Try declaring `extern std::vector<std::vector<int>>  v` to declare it in the header.

Comment: Wrap it up inside a simple matrix class and let the constructor do all the work for you.

Comment: im aware that i shouldnt be defining vectors in a header, thats why im asking how to define it in the same kind of simple way in the cpp file, because this along with like 100 other vectors will be what represents the unique maps in a tile-based engine im working on.